# Elasticsearch stop words relative path

Tags: elasticsearch, config, stop-words

Can somebody tell me please what [elasticsearch documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/analysis-stop-tokenfilter.html#analysis-stop-tokenfilter) means by **relative path to config directory**? I dont see any in ES instalation. I need to find a stop words file which is defined in es index like `"stopwords_path": "stopwords/slovak.txt"` but I cant find any file with this name. May be Win 10 is not able to find it cause it has really poor search engine. Thanks a lot.

Comment: did you create this `slovak.txt` yourself ?

Comment: What are you talking about? I did it log time ago.

Comment: sorry for misunderstanding, have a nice day ahead :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As written in the documentation you should create the file slovak.txt according this syntax:

> A path (either relative to config location, or absolute) to a
>   stopwords file configuration. Each stop word should be in its own
>   "line" (separated by a line break). The file must be UTF-8 encoded.

so you should create a slowak.txt file like this:

```
a
aby
aj
ak
aká
akáže
aké
akého
akéhože
akej
akejže
akému
akémuže
akéže
ako
akom
akomže
akou
akouže
akože
akú
akúže
aký
akých
akýchže
akým
akými
akýmiže
akýmže
akýže
ale
alebo
ani
áno
asi
avšak
až
ba
bez
bezo
bol
bola
boli
bolo
buď
bude
budem
budeme
budeš
budete
budú
by
byť
cez
cezo
čej
či
čí
čia
čie
čieho
čiemu
čím
čími
čiu
čo
čoho
čom
čomu
čou
čože
ďalší
ďalšia
ďalšie
ďalšieho
ďalšiemu
ďalších
ďalším
ďalšími
ďalšiu
ďalšom
ďalšou
dnes
do
ešte
ho
hoci
i
iba
ich
im
iná
iné
iného
inej
inému
iní
inom
inú
iný
iných
iným
inými
ja
je
jeho
jej
jemu
ju
k
ká
kam
kamže
každá
každé
každého
každému
každí
každou
každú
každý
každých
každým
každými
káže
kde
ké
keď
keďže
kej
kejže
kéže
kie
kieho
kiehože
kiemu
kiemuže
kieže
koho
kom
komu
kou
kouže
kto
ktorá
ktoré
ktorej
ktorí
ktorou
ktorú
ktorý
ktorých
ktorým
ktorými
ku
kú
kúže
ký
kýho
kýhože
kým
kýmu
kýmuže
kýže
lebo
leda
ledaže
len
ma
má
majú
mal
mala
mali
mám
máme
máš
mať
máte
medzi
mi
mňa
mne
mnou
moja
moje
mojej
mojich
mojim
mojimi
mojou
moju
možno
môcť
môj
môjho
môže
môžem
môžeme
môžeš
môžete
môžu
mu
musí
musia
musieť
musím
musíme
musíš
musíte
my
na
nad
nado
najmä
nám
nami
nás
náš
naša
naše
našej
nášho
naši
našich
našim
našimi
našou
ne
neho
nech
nej
nejaká
nejaké
nejakého
nejakej
nejakému
nejakom
nejakou
nejakú
nejaký
nejakých
nejakým
nejakými
nemu
než
nič
ničím
ničoho
ničom
ničomu
nie
niečo
niektorá
niektoré
niektorého
niektorej
niektorému
niektorom
niektorou
niektorú
niektorý
niektorých
niektorým
niektorými
nielen
nich
nim
ním
nimi
no
ňom
ňou
ňu
o
od
odo
on
oň
ona
oňho
oni
ono
ony
po
pod
podľa
podo
pokiaľ
popod
popri
potom
poza
práve
pre
prečo
pred
predo
preto
pretože
pri
s
sa
seba
sebe
sebou
sem
si
sme
so
som
ste
sú
svoj
svoja
svoje
svojho
svojich
svojim
svojím
svojimi
svojou
svoju
ta
tá
tak
taká
takáto
také
takéto
takej
takejto
takého
takéhoto
takému
takémuto
takí
taký
takýto
takú
takúto
takže
tam
táto
teba
tebe
tebou
teda
tej
tejto
ten
tento
ti
tí
tie
tieto
tiež
títo
to
toho
tohto
tohoto
tom
tomto
tomu
tomuto
toto
tou
touto
tu
tú
túto
tvoj
tvoja
tvoje
tvojej
tvojho
tvoji
tvojich
tvojim
tvojím
tvojimi
ty
tých
tým
tými
týmto
u
už
v
vám
vami
vás
váš
vaša
vaše
vašej
vášho
vaši
vašich
vašim
vaším
veď
viac
vo
však
všetci
všetka
všetko
všetky
všetok
vy
z
za
začo
začože
zo
že
```

This file have to be inside `ES_PATH_CONF` so in linux is `/etc/elasticsearch/` and in windows is `C:\ProgramData\Elastic\Elasticsearch\config` Then you follow relative path notation. So if it is `C:\ProgramData\Elastic\Elasticsearch\config\slowak.txt`, you should set your path in this way:

```
"stopwords_path":"slowak.txt"
```

if you would put it inside `C:\ProgramData\Elastic\Elasticsearch\config\synonym\slowak.txt` you you set:

```
"stopwords_path":"synonym\slowak.txt"
```

Comment: But this file and this index is already created. I dont want to create one. I need to find this one.

Comment: is slowak.txt file inside  C:\ProgramData\Elastic\Elasticsearch\config\stopwords/slovak.txt ? If not elasticsearch can not see your file

Comment: Yes. This is it C:\ProgramData\Elastic\Elasticsearch\config

Answer (score 1):

What this documentation means is that you can provide your own path or use the relative file to define your own stop words in a text file.

if you are using the relative path then it should be inside your config folder or elasticsearch, where your `elasticsearch.yml` is present.

If you choose to have an absolute path, then you can store this file to **any location where elasticsearch has access.**

**Just reproduced your issue and used [GET Settings API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-get-settings.html) to tell the current location of this file**

For example:

```
GET yourindex/_settings
```

Retrurns the path which you gave while creating this setting.

```
{
    "stopwords": {
        "settings": {
            "index": {
                "number_of_shards": "1",
                "provided_name": "stopwords",
                "creation_date": "1587374021579",
                "analysis": {
                    "filter": {
                        "my_stop": {
                            "type": "stop",
                            "stopwords": [
                                "and",
                                "is",
                                "the"
                            ],
                            "stopwords_path": "opster.txt". -> this is the file location which in this is relative
                        }
                    }
                },
                "number_of_replicas": "1",
                "uuid": "EQyF7JydTXGXoebh52yNpg",
                "version": {
                    "created": "7060199"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Update: an example with the absolute path given by me on my tar installation of Elasticsearch on the ubuntu EC2 machine and using [same GET index setting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-get-settings.html) figures out that.

Comment: But it is realtive path. The answer is C:\ProgramData\Elastic\Elasticsearch\config

Comment: @Čamo, well I mentioned how to figure out using the API :), so that's the best way to figure out what path you gave, isn't it as then it would be helpful for all the users irrespective of relative or absolute path or based on operating system :)

Comment: yeah as you created it inside the config folder which Elastic consider for relative path